# SQL Adventure Works Getting Immediate Manager

Tags: sql-server, adventureworks

How may I modify the following procedure to get the direct/immediate manager only?  I don't want to get all the managers of an individual.  Only the immediate manager.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspGetEmployeeManagers]
    @EmployeeID [int]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Use recursive query to list out all Employees required for a particular Manager
    WITH [EMP_cte]([EmployeeID], [ManagerID], [FirstName], [LastName], [Title], [RecursionLevel]) -- CTE name and columns
    AS (
        SELECT e.[EmployeeID], e.[ManagerID], c.[FirstName], c.[LastName], e.[Title], 0 -- Get the initial Employee
        FROM [HumanResources].[Employee] e 
            INNER JOIN [Person].[Contact] c 
            ON e.[ContactID] = c.[ContactID]
        WHERE e.[EmployeeID] = @EmployeeID
        UNION ALL
        SELECT e.[EmployeeID], e.[ManagerID], c.[FirstName], c.[LastName], e.[Title], [RecursionLevel] + 1 -- Join recursive member to anchor
        FROM [HumanResources].[Employee] e 
            INNER JOIN [EMP_cte]
            ON e.[EmployeeID] = [EMP_cte].[ManagerID]
            INNER JOIN [Person].[Contact] c 
            ON e.[ContactID] = c.[ContactID]
    )
    -- Join back to Employee to return the manager name 
    SELECT [EMP_cte].[RecursionLevel], [EMP_cte].[EmployeeID], [EMP_cte].[FirstName], [EMP_cte].[LastName], 
        [EMP_cte].[ManagerID], c.[FirstName] AS 'ManagerFirstName', c.[LastName] AS 'ManagerLastName'  -- Outer select from the CTE
    FROM [EMP_cte] 
        INNER JOIN [HumanResources].[Employee] e 
        ON [EMP_cte].[ManagerID] = e.[EmployeeID]
        INNER JOIN [Person].[Contact] c 
        ON e.[ContactID] = c.[ContactID]
    ORDER BY [RecursionLevel], [ManagerID], [EmployeeID]
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 25) 
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspGetEmployeeManagers]
    @EmployeeID [int]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT 
        e.[EmployeeID], e.[ManagerID], c.[FirstName], c.[LastName], e.[Title],
        hr.[EmployeeID], hr.[ManagerID], chr.[FirstName], chr.[LastName], hr.[Title]
    FROM [HumanResources].[Employee] e
    -- get info of employee 
    INNER JOIN [Person].[Contact] c 
        ON e.[ContactID] = c.[ContactID]
    -- get the info of immediate manager 
    LEFT JOIN [HumanResources].[Employee] hr 
        ON e.[ManagerID] = hr.[EmployeeID]
    LEFT JOIN [Person].[Contact] chr 
        ON hr.[ContactID] = chr.[ContactID]
    WHERE e.[EmployeeID] = @EmployeeID
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or replacing

```
 -- Join back to Employee to return the manager name 
    SELECT [EMP_cte].[RecursionLevel], [EMP_cte].[EmployeeID], [EMP_cte].[FirstName], [EMP_cte].[LastName], 
        [EMP_cte].[ManagerID], c.[FirstName] AS 'ManagerFirstName', c.[LastName] AS 'ManagerLastName'  -- Outer select from the CTE
    FROM [EMP_cte] 
        INNER JOIN [HumanResources].[Employee] e 
        ON [EMP_cte].[ManagerID] = e.[EmployeeID]
        INNER JOIN [Person].[Contact] c 
        ON e.[ContactID] = c.[ContactID]
    ORDER BY [RecursionLevel], [ManagerID], [EmployeeID]
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 25)
```

with

```
 -- Join back to Employee to return the manager name 
    SELECT **top 1** [EMP_cte].[RecursionLevel], [EMP_cte].[EmployeeID], [EMP_cte].[FirstName], [EMP_cte].[LastName], 
        [EMP_cte].[ManagerID], c.[FirstName] AS 'ManagerFirstName', c.[LastName] AS 'ManagerLastName'  -- Outer select from the CTE
    FROM [EMP_cte] 
        INNER JOIN [HumanResources].[Employee] e 
        ON [EMP_cte].[ManagerID] = e.[EmployeeID]
        INNER JOIN [Person].[Contact] c 
        ON e.[ContactID] = c.[ContactID]
    ORDER BY [RecursionLevel], [ManagerID], [EmployeeID]
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 25)
```